# A problem in Jeffrey M. Lee's "Manifolds and Differential Geometry". ((2) pp.122)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

The problem statement is the following:

Let $f:M \to N$ be a $C^\infty$ map. Suppose that $M$ is compact and $N$ is connected. If $f$ is injective and $T_pf$ is an isomorphism for each $p \in M$, then show that $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

There are two issues I encounter in this problem. First, I can't show that $f$ is surjective. Secondly, if I restrict the map's codomain to the image, $f:M \to f(M)$ is a bijection. Applying the inverse mapping theorem it is easily obtained that $f^{-1}$ is also $C^\infty$. Thus $f$ is a diffeomorphism even without the assumptions that $M$ is compact and $N$ is connected. Intuitively, the assumptions of compactness and connectedness are unrelated to the surjectivity of $f$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They are very much related to surjectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the inverse mapping theorem, the image of $f$ is open. On the other hand, the image of a compact space under a continuous map is compact. As $N$ is Hausdorff, every compact subset is closed. Surjectivity now follows from connectivity of $N$.

Comment: I see it now, thank you.